# Matlab using subscript variable

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, functions, matlab

I'm trying to write a function in matlab but I don't quite know if it is working. In the equation line i have:

```
xdot(2) = N_h * x;
```

to signify:
$$\frac{dy}{dt} = N_h \cdot x$$

But should the matlab code be:

```
xdot(2) = Nh * x
```

Or is the first one correct? Or are they both correct?

Comment: Depends on the rest of your code.

Comment: @Batman there's just one line before it: `xdot(1) = e*(1-x)`...out of curiosity, how exactly does it depend on the rest of the code?

Comment: Syntactically Matlab can understand both. Usually everyone develops his own style and keeps using it. There exist some so called "standard notation", but they are for professionals who read and write a large amount of code regularly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quick enough, this test script:

```
Mh=1;
M_h=2;
disp(Mh);
disp(M_h);
```

works on Matlab R2009a, this is it prints
$$1$$
$$2$$

---

I'm not really sure if `M_h` may be recommnded, but `Mh` and `M_h` are both valid names for a variable or constant.